# Python ImportError (most likely due to a circular import) for pip install but not local setup.py

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setup.py, pypi

I have a simple Python package for plotting scientific data called `pliffy`. The code is hosted on Github in [this repo](https://github.com/MartinHeroux/pliffy). I have published it on PyPi [here](https://pypi.org/project/pliffy/).

I received a [Github issue](https://github.com/MartinHeroux/pliffy/issues/20) from a colleague trying to use the package. Basically, doing `pip install pliffy` installs the package, but when you start a Python interpreter and try to import the package you get the follow error message:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'figure' from partially initialized module 'pliffy' (most likely due to a circular import) ([...]/testing/pliffy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pliffy/__init__.py)
```

I have been able to reproduce the issue on my own machine after creating a fresh Python environment and pip-intalling my package (yes, I now know the importance of testing your own packages after you push them to Pypi; won't make that mistake again!)

However, if I do the following -- clone and local install -- I don't get the error message:

```
git clone https://github.com/MartinHeroux/pliffy.git
cd pliffy/
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
python
```

```
>>> import pliffy
>>> pliffy.demo.demo()
```

I have run into trouble with circular imports when using type-hinting my own classes/objects, but I thought I solved everything given that I was able to install and use my package locally.

I did try changing the import statements in my plot.py module to import only `pliffy` rather than `from pliffy import estimate, figure, parse`, but that did not solve the problem. And because the problem only seems to appear after I have created the Python wheel and pushed it to PyPi, I have to bump and push a version in order to figure out it is not working (i.e. it works when I install the package locally).

In case it would be useful, here is how I create my wheel and push my package to PyPi:

```
pip install twine
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/* # as a test 
twine upload dist/*
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update: Additional info**

Dear Justin, thank you for taking the time to read through my question and asking for more information.

In response to your question, I create a local environment, locally installed my package (i.e. pliffy), and started up a Python interpreter *not* in the package folder. I gott an error message when I tried to import my package, but a different error this time:

```
>>> import pliffy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/martin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pliffy-0.1.2-py3.8.egg/pliffy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'figure' from 'pliffy' (/home/martin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pliffy-0.1.2-py3.8.egg/pliffy/__init__.py)
```

This tells me that previously I was not getting an error because I was starting the Python interpreter when I was in the package directory. Why I get an error (and a different one at that) when I start the Python interpreter *not* in the package folder is not clear to me.

Dustin, you also asked about the import structure. I am not too sure how much (little) info, but I decided to provide eveything:

```
pliffy
├── __init__.py             
├── demo.py
├── estimate.py
├── parser.py
├── plot.py
├── utils.py
└── figure
    ├── diff_axis.py
    ├── figure_ab.py
    ├── figure_diff.py
    ├── figure.py
    └── __init__.py
```

****init**.py**
[Only bottom two import are needed for API, but other imports were needed to be able to get my test suite to work (this may not be needed, but when I coded this, I could not tests these other modules unless I included explicite imports here).]

```
from . import estimate
from . import plot
from . import utils
from . import figure
from . import parser
from . import demo
from pliffy.plot import plot_abd
from pliffy.utils import PliffyInfoABD, ABD
```

**demo.py**

```
from pliffy.utils import PliffyInfoABD, ABD
from pliffy.plot import plot_abd
```

**estimate.py**

```
from pliffy.utils import ABD
```

**parser.py**

```
from pliffy import estimate
from pliffy import utils
```

**plot.py**

```
import pliffy
```

**utils.py**

```
from pliffy import estimate
```

**figure/**init**.py**

```
from .figure import Figure
from .figure_ab import FigureAB
from .figure_diff import FigureDiff
from .diff_axis import DiffAxCreator
```

**figure/diff_axis.py**

```
from pliffy import utils, parser
```

**figure/figure.py**

```
from pliffy.parser import Xticks, Raw, Mean, CI, Paired
```

**figure/figure_ab.py**

```
from pliffy.figure import Figure
from pliffy import parser
```

**figure/figure_diff.py**

```
from pliffy.figure import Figure
from pliffy import parser
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Does your local version work when you're not in the `pliffy` directory? Can you give us some examples of your import structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into your published wheel and indeed it does not contain your `figure` sub-package.

In order to understand why, lets check your `setup.py`

you declared your packages as `packages=["pliffy"]` but you did not declared `pliffy.figure` sub-package. Becasue of this, the wheel packager just did not take it.

A better and standard way is to use `setuptools` `find_packages()` function that do the packages discovery for you.

`packages=find_packages()`

Comment: Dear Lior, thank you for figuring this out for me. Adding find_packages did the trick. I learned a lot making this package, and I am continuing to learn thanks for generous folks like yourself. Thanks for helping me out. It is very much appreciated!